# Interstitial sites: edge and face sharing?

Tags: solid-state-chemistry, molecular-structure

In close packed structures there is one octahedral hole per close packed atom. In a HCP unit cell these octahedra form a chain of face sharing polyhedra. Is this this universal in close packing or only common to HCP?

More generally this question is "how do we know when interstitial sites (T± and Oh) share edges or a faces?"